# preventing padding-left from pushing other items left

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to place the id "homescore" to the right of the id "hometeam" using padding-left (pl in tailwind).

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
const Matches = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center league-container  hover:bg-slate-100' id="teams">
        <div className='flex items-center' id='hometeam'>
          <img className='w-18 h-18' src={props.homeLogo}></img>
          <h2 className='pl-2 font-semibold'>{props.homeName}</h2>
          <h2 className="font-bold pl-16" id="homescore">1</h2>
        </div>
        <div className='flex items-center pt-1 ' id='awayteam'>
          <img className='w-18 h-18' src={props.awayLogo}></img>
          <h2 className='pl-2 font-semibold'>{props.awayName}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Matches;
```

This has the following effect => [image]

As you can see this just pushes both "homeLogo", and "homeName" to the left when their position should remain the same.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

I kind of got it to work => [image]
But a issue remains. It seems the score still not being aligned properly, likely due to text length, see screenshots for reference => [image] [image]
It seems the longer the text is the more the score is being pushed to the right.

**Updated react code** =>

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
const Matches = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-start justify-center league-container px-16 hover:bg-slate-100' id="teams">
        <div className=' flex justify-between items-center' id='hometeam'>
          <img className='w-18 h-18 flex-none' src={props.homeLogo}></img>
          <h2 className='pl-2 font-semibold'>{props.homeName}</h2>
          <h2 className="font-bold pl-16  text-green-600" id="homescore">1</h2>
        </div>
       <div className='flex justify-between items-center pt-1 ' id='awayteam'>
        <img className='w-18 h-18 flex-none' src={props.awayLogo}></img>
        <h2 className='pl-2 font-semibold'>{props.awayName}</h2>
        <h2 className="font-bold pl-16 text-green-600" id="awayscore">1</h2>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Matches;
```

Comment: isn't it because you have `justify-center` on the parent?  If those child divs aren't a fixed width then the spacing will be different for each one

Comment: That may very well be the cause. What would you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are trying to do:

```
<div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
  <div className='flex flex-col items-start justify-center league-container px-16 hover:bg-slate-100' id="teams">
    <div className='w-full flex justify-between items-center' id='hometeam'>
      <img className='w-18 h-18 flex-none' src={props.homeLogo}></img>
      <h2 className='pl-2 font-semibold'>{props.homeName}</h2>
      <h2 className="font-bold pl-16" id="homescore">1</h2>
    </div>
    <div className='flex justify-between items-center pt-1 ' id='awayteam'>
      <img className='w-18 h-18 flex-none' src={props.awayLogo}></img>
      <h2 className='pl-2 font-semibold'>{props.awayName}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I re-engineered the code a bit and moved the padding to the parent block with `px-16`. Then I further set the children divs to be flex-ed and their corresponding content justified with `space-between` so as to extend and somewhat float both the `homescore` and `hometeam` divs to the horizontal ends of the parent div.

With the above code, I was able to achieve something like this:

[image]

You can adjust the padding on the parent block as you prefer. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Cheers

Comment: Cheers mate this kind of helped. But I still have some problems, would appreciate if you could take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Nevermind I got it